# How can I pass an input/Textbox Field to Controller? ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've a Form and a simple model with following input Fields:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string Article { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Notice { get; set; }
}
```

My Form looks like this

[image]

I can catch the Values on my Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "OrderID,OrderDate,Article,Price,Notice")] Order order)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Orders.Add(order);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(order);
        }
```

So. I want to add dynamic fields with jQuery. That works fine but I don't know how to get the values from the Multiple input fields. And that's my Problem.

So I want to create for each Order an Entity. (How in the last image)

Please take a look at the last image

[image]

That's the result that I want to have! How can I get this resulut in ASP.NET MVC C#? I work with the Entity Framework 6 
Thank you for your Help!

[image]

Comment: just create the another actionMethod ...Like Expected parameter list<Order> ordersdetails.....Pass All input field value to collection..

Comment: So you are trying to create a page where the user can add multiple items of the model, right?  You need to create a model with a list of the model.

Comment: @Dean.DePue Yes right that is what I want. Do you mean List<Order> myList in the Create Controller? Can you show me an example?

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj Do you mean after passing the Create method to redirect with RedirectToAction to my Listmethod?

Comment: chek out this [question][1] as i understand it addresses the same issue


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110614/net-mvc-submitting-multiple-models-of-the-same-type-at-once

Comment: @HarisBjelic  There are many ways to do it.  Some here have suggested using a List<Order>.  I have used a method by using jQuery to add another set of fields extending the id by a number.  Then cycling through them with a another JavaScript call and posting each one at a time with an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change your actions to accept a `List<Order>` parameters (or a strongly typed viewmodel with a property of `List<Order>` type):

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Create()
 {         
     var model = new List<Order>();
     return View(model);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Create(List<Order> orders)
 {
     // Update code omitted
     return View(order);
 }
```

Then in your view add a model declaration:

```
@model List<Order>;
```

Now the part you need to get correct is the naming of your dynamically added `Order` objects on your HTML input names to keep the model binder happy.

When creating the first order item on your input names should be:

```
Name="[0].Id"
Name="[0].OrderDate"
Name="[0].Article"
Name="[0].Price"
Name="[0].Notice"
```

This will be the first order and so on etc:

```
Name="[1].Id"
Name="[1].OrderDate"
Name="[1].Article"
Name="[1].Price"
Name="[1].Notice"
```

This article is well worth a read:

[**Model Binding To A List**](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)